# Should I worry about a permit for a Metal RV cover

Tags: cover

Since this these are not considered a permanent structure and moveable, should I not worry if I don't get a permit from county? I am outside the city limits and rural area on 2 acres. RV cover will be 12ft wide x 31ft long and 11ft tall. Made from square 14 gauge metal and metal roof. Meets snow load requirements for my area, etc. Quality unit and I am having it professionally installed.

Comment: I think this question is going to be hard to answer without more specifics about the structure and your location. And in the end, it really comes down to your risk tolerance, which no one here is going to be able to assess.

Comment: @mathewbourque - Would you?

Comment: Whether you need a permit or not, and the penalty for building without a permit (if any), depends 100% on location - state at a minimum and likely county or even city/town. My *hunch* is that out on your own 2 acres nobody will care. Since you're having it professionally installed, find an installer you can trust and ask them what they think.

Comment: If permit is required by the locals, and you do not get one, they can make you take it down and remove it.Asking locals first is usually free and permit probably not that expensive.

Comment: It's just a pain. I have to meet with them first, provide drawing and installation instructions, then they have to come out and inspect site before and after. I am not worried about the cost, just making me jump though hoops for a metal RV cover is absurd. If it was stick built and permanent then I get it. And the companies that sell these want a couple hundred more for certified drawing units. Just seems like another way for the state to make money and line companies pockets.

Comment: @Dean -- I take it your jurisdiction doesn't have a way to submit permit applications online?

Comment: If you are having a licensed contractor set it up and anchor it they should know if a permit is required. I would verify that the anchors being installed meet the maximum wind load for your location. I have seen metal buildings and covers trying out for the wizard of Oz, well actually viewed it happening and the aftermath of a few others.

Comment: @Dean I probably would get the permit, but I haven't done a lot of projects like that, and so I'd likely be extra cautious about it in general.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it pertains to local code. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Depends.  What are the penalties for failing to pull a permit? *You don't know, do you?*. The locality is not stupid, they know people don't want to bother with pulling permits.  So many have adjusted their punishments accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I always told people before I was the Code Officer was "Call and ask the code officer" They know the answer.  In my area a permit was required and most of the time was $25.00 including a one time inspection.

Comment: When I sign a contract to do work I make sure it specifies it is the responsibility of the contractor to acquire all permits and have necessary inspections completed. I have even written it in the memo section of a deposit check.

Answer (score 3):

Entirely dependent on the Local Area Having Jurisdiction (LAHJ.) State, county, city/town/village whatever it may be that sets your local building rules.

Can be VERY expensive not to. My LAHJ will **backcharge a daily fine** not from when they notice it, but from when they can determine you installed it until it's taken down or permitted, and the daily fine is more than the cost of the permit, per day.

So, read the applicable building or zoning ordinances for your local area, and if it's not *clear* that the structure *IS* exempted, either ask the LAHJ to clarify that for you, or get the permit. It may be a lot LESS expensive than building it un-permitted, if a permit is required.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Building Permit issues (i.e.: strong enough, anchored down properly, etc.) there are zoning issues: (i.e.: setback issues, percent of land covered, etc.).

If a permit is required and you have an event (seismic activity or wind storm) and the canopy comes apart and hurts someone or damages your Rv, your insurance may not cover you.

Comment: The OP said he was having it professionally installed so the installers would assume/incur any liability.   Hopefully they know about all that other stuff too.

Comment: @SteveWellens Most state and county regulations require the home owner to obtain all permits and pay all fees. This is so they have a real entity to come back on after a few years. The liability lies with the home owner.

Comment: @SteveWellens -- installers could, indeed, be responsible for any liability, if they can be found and if they're solvent. But that doesn't mean the owner isn't responsible, and it doesn't mean that an injured party has to chase down the installers rather than seek compensation from the owner.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer? Yes, you will **likely** need a permit to build your **RV Cover**. In most districts, you’ll find that building a structure requires getting a permit. **Depending on your local jurisdiction**, you will need to pass certain inspections and requirements. It’s important to find out what you need to do to get your building permit. It’s equally important to research what inspections you’ll need to undergo to get the green light on your project.

It is totally inadvisable to begin your project without checking into the local requirement, and/or getting a permit, first. Please read [this article](https://www.versatube.com/news/Do-I-Need-a-Permit-to-Build-My-VersaTube-RV-Cover-blog/#:%7E:text=The%20short%20answer%3F%20Yes%2C%20you%20will%20likely%20need,need%20to%20do%20to%20get%20your%20building%20permit.) for why should you get a permit, if required.